# Object oriented programming: Method Capabilities

Tags: java, methods

I'm sorry for, maybe, repeating the same question once again, but I'm lost and don't know where to go. After tons of googling and RTFMing everything I can find on methods I still can't find an answer that would satisfy me.

Object oriented programming is relatively new to me (with several years of experience with procedural programming), and not one tutorial can describe what exactly methods and classes can do.

For example: I have a method that calculates a *bunch* of results from 2 long variables; After calculation is done, I want my program to take two other variables, do the same thing with them but write the results in different variables, so I can have the result of first AND second calculation.

What I did: I set up a do while loop with a lot of cases in it. Each case places different variables for calculating and, after calculation, variable for queue does a step so loop will run again through a different case. And this is how I'd write with procedural programming

But there must be a way to do this more elegantly, by using methods. And now, the main question:
**Can methods output several variables without writing bits of code for sending the result to already declared placeholders? Can you input several variables in your method when you call it? What is the syntax for doing this?**

Lastly, can someone give me a pointer on where to find a good java tutorial? Everything I've found either treats me like a child with bicycle examples or full of technical information I don't understand yet.

Comment: `BunchOfResults first = compute(a, b); BunchOfResults second = compute(c, d);`? If you want something closer to your code, then show us your code instead of describing it. To take a more concrete example, you could imagine bicycles, which are complex objects made of many parts, and a factory of bicycles. This would result in `Bicycle b1 = factory.create(LARGE, RED); Bicycle b2 = factory.create(SMALL, BLUE);`. That is not treating you like a child. Adults use bicycle too, and everyone knows what a bicyle is and does. What matters is the principles behind the example.

Comment: Have you looked through the standard Oracle tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ It's actually pretty good.

Comment: You would do well to read Peter Coad's book on Java Design, currently in the second edition.  http://www.amazon.com/Java-Design-Building-Better-Applets/dp/0139111816/ref=la_B000APIAUC_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422097637&sr=1-6      The other book Java Modeling in Color with UML (http://www.amazon.com/Java-Modeling-Color-UML-Enterprise/dp/013011510X/ref=la_B000APIAUC_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422097637&sr=1-5) will help you understand the mental model shift you need to make.  In Object Oriented programming you design around the "things" involved , not the order you want to do something.

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting code. It's huge and barely readable, so I thought that describing an algorithm I used would be better.
I don't have anything against bicycle example but it's too far from actually explaining what happens in your PC when classes and methods are called and what happens when they are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example: I have a method that calculates a bunch of results from 2 long variables

That sounds like you should encapsulate the results in a new class then, and use method parameters for the two inputs. Any time you have multiple related values, that's at least a *hint* that bundling them together in a class might be a good idea.

> After calculation is done, I want my program to take two other variables, do the same thing with them but write the results in different variables, so I can have the result of first AND second calculation.

With the above approach, that just means calling the method again, passing in two different inputs:

```
CalculationResult result1 = calculateResult(x1, x2);
CalculationResult result2 = calculateResult(y1, y2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I thought that something like this would happen in Java but wasn't sure how exactly make it happen. Now I know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like tuples in Scala. Never used them myself but they should work pretty easily.

```
def compute(x: Long, y: Long) {
  return ("Hello", y + 100, x)
}

val(hello, yPlus100, x) values = compute(3123, 3123);
println(values.yPlus100) // 3223
```

Though in Java the cleanest way would be doing a returnment  class, I guess, but then you have to create a new class for each, if you have multiple different methods returning multiple values differently.

So in Java it would be something like:

```
public final class Tuple2<A, B> {

    public A a;
    public B b;

    public Tuple2(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Which would then be used like:

```
public Tuple2<Integer, String> compute() {
    return new Tuple2<>(5, "Hello");
}

Tuple2<Integer, String> values = compute();
System.put.println(values.b); // "Hello"
```